# Change Spring form tag path value

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-form

I need to convert "lastModified" to millisecond.Normally it is Date() format.But i must send it as a millisecond.How I can change path variable from jsp or my controller ? Or you can suggest other way.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: share your organization model class and controller method.

Comment: Here it is .I have edit it .Now you can see model class and controller method .

Comment: You should always post actual code instead of screenshot, that will help us to give solution quicker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a transient long field and use it like below inside your Organization entity class.

```
public class Organization {

    --------------
    --------------

    @Transient
    private long lastModifiedMili;

    public long getLastModifiedMili() {
        return lastModified.getTime();
    }

    public void setLastModifiedMili(long lastModifiedMili) {
        this.lastModifiedMili = lastModifiedMili;
        this.lastModified = new Date(lastModifiedMili);
    }

    public Organization(Long id, String name, String address, long lastModifiedMili) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name=name;
        this.address = address;
        this.lastModifiedMili = lastModifiedMili;
        this.lastModified = new Date(lastModifiedMili);
    }
}
```

And inside your form use this:

```
<form:hidden path="lastModifiedMili" />
```